# JAXB parsing an xml file where properties are on a single line

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have this particular xml file(in that exact format) that I am trying to parse with JAXB
Because the properties are all on a single line it doesn't see them and returns all fields as null in my main function. How can I parse the xml correctly in it's format?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
<employee firstName="Asya" id="2" lastname="Olshansky"/>
</employees>
```

This is the code for employee

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
 
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
 
    //Setters and Getters
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
   }
```

Employees code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employees")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees {
    @XmlElement(name = "employee")
    List<Employee> employees = null;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> list) {
        this.employees = list;
    }

}
```

This is the Main execution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String fileName = "employee.xml";
     
            jaxbXmlFileToObject(fileName);
        }
     
        private static void jaxbXmlFileToObject(String fileName) {
             
            File xmlFile = new File(fileName);
             
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            try
            {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employees.class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                
                Employees employees = (Employees) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
                 
                for(Employee e: employees.getEmployees() )
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            catch (JAXBException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**Employee.java:**

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
 
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Employee(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
   }
```

**Employees.java:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="employees")
public class Employees {
    
    List<Employee> employees;
    
    public Employees() {}
    
    public Employees(List<Employee> employees) {
        super();
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="employee")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> list) {
        this.employees = list;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

1. No changes in `Main`.
2. Updated `Employee` and `Employees` class.
3. Added `@XmlAttribute` in `Employee` to map attribute names and getter/setters.
4. Added `@XmlElement` in `Employees` to map each `employee` element inside the `employees` tag and constructor also.

Comment: Can you explain why @XmlAttribute instead of @XmlElement?
Or can you redirect to a source where I can read about it

Comment: @Asa `@XmlAttribute` is used for attributes i.e. `id`, `firstname` etc in your case, `@XmlElement` indicated element name i.e. `employee` in your case. Let me know if you it works for you

Comment: Yes it worked! Where can I read more about it to understand when to use what?